# How to define an array of unknown size in c++?

Tags: c++

Suppose a_1 is known and ***a_2, ..., a_q*** can be computed recursively by  ***a_k=a_{k-1} + f(k)***, where ***f(k)*** is some function of ***k***.

However q is minimum number such that ***a_1+ \sum_{k=2}^q f(k) >= 1000*** and unknown.

I want to find ***a_2,..., a_q*** using c++. A straight-forward way is to find the ***q*** first; then initialize an array of size ***q*** and store the value in to an array, as follows.

However, I feel it computed f(k) twice and is a waste of resource. Is there any way I can initialize an unknown size array in c++ and solve it in one loop?

```
//find the max ***q*** first       
int k=1;
int sum=a_1;
while(sum < 1000){
     int inc = some equation of k;
     sum += inc;
     k++;

//compute a_2, ..., a_q
int array[k-1];
int sum=a_1;
for(int h=0; h<k; h++){
     int inc = some equation of k;  // repeated computation
     sum += inc;
     array[h]=sum;
}
```

Comment: You can use dynamic memory, allocating with new[], and resizing as needed. (or maybe the C functions malloc, realloc, free could be nice although in general they are not that good)

Comment: @PaulStelian wat?  Just use a `std::vector` and do `push_back`.

Comment: `std::vector` is the answer, but you'll probably be better off if you just read something on containers and algorithms in general, it's a crucial part of c++

Comment: @Henri Well I got used to doing those things here at my Uni, forgot about vectors (our homeworks didn't allow them)

Comment: @PaulStelian Not allowing `std::vector` in your homework (unless the homework is to write a vector), is like forbidding you to use a keyboard to type, how is that productive education.

Comment: @PasserBy Well that's how it has been here at Data Structures, using `std::vector` wasn't really allowed for the first homework since we had to implement array-based lists, and then we used the builtin `std::list` for the other things. Oh well

Comment: @PaulStelian Don't use `std::list` if you can help it at all. `std::vector` almost always outperform

Comment: @PasserBy Well we did not need to do random access within the lists and we are taught to save memory as much as possible when performance isn't affected.

Answer (score 1):

Using a vector will be a good solution.
In vector, you don't even need to worry about the new entries - allocation (and deletion later if any) as the vector will take care of it without your knowledge.
And also it gives a lot of options than a regular array.

Answer (score 0):

Use either `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`.

See embedded comments:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

int some_equation(int k) { return 0; }

void test(int a_1)
{
  //find the max ***q*** first       
  int k=1;
  int sum=a_1;
  while(sum < 1000){
        int inc = some_equation(k);
        sum += inc;
        k++;

    //
    // 2 alternate methods - you should normally prefer the std::vector approach
    //
    auto array = std::vector<int>(k-1);   // should this be k-1? don't you need k elements?
//    auto array = std::make_unique<int[]>(k-1);

    int sum=a_1;
    for(int h=0; h<k; h++){
        int inc = some_equation(k);  // repeated computation
        sum += inc;
        array[h]=sum;
    } 
  }
}
```